# How to change the icon in liferay portal

Tags: java, eclipse, icons, liferay, portlet

I want to change the icon in liferay portlet. How can I change the icon and what is the use of icon.png in liferay portlet?

```
/PORTLET-NAME/
    build.xml
    /docroot/
        /css/
        /js/
        /WEB-INF/
            /src/ (not created by default)
            liferay-display.xml
            liferay-plugin-package.properties
            liferay-portlet.xml
            portlet.xml
            web.xml
        icon.png
        view.jsp
```

Comment: Icon.png is default image icon displayed in your portlet top left corner just before Portlet title.. If you need your image to be displayed replace default icon.png with yours keeping the name same..

Comment: @AnkitP why not add this as answer? IMHO it answers what the author asks for. (maybe add liferay-portlet.xml as the location to change/configure the actual icon)

Answer (score 4):

- Icon.png is default image icon displayed in your portlet, At top left corner just before Portlet title. If you want to use your image replace default icon.png with yours keeping the name same.

OR As Olaf Kock suggested

- Update your image path / name in liferay-portlet.xml as the location to change/configure icon.png

`<icon>/newicon.png</icon>`

Answer (score 2):

Better option is to create a new theme with pluginsSDK, (copy the classic theme for starting) and then replace the portal favicon in the new theme folder with new one.

Alternatively, add the following code in `portal-ext.properties` file:

```
theme.shortcut.icon=your_new_icon.ico
```